# Can't get data from Facebook Marketing API insights - error #273

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to get the data from Facebook Marketing API insights and receiving the following message: (#273) This Ads API call requires the user to be admin of the ad account. User is not admin on ad account XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.

I did all the things, described in the documentation:
- created the app
- in the Advanced settings -> Advertising Accounts added client's Ad Account
- added Marketing API into the Products section
- generated Access token with the ads_read, read_insights, even ads_management permissions

The client's Account ID is added to Marketing API -> Settings -> Ads API Account Configuration.

My account has Administrator role in the application.

What can cause the problem?

Comment: So the access token was created using the client's account?

Comment: Most likely the error is correct because the user who the access token you are using the access the API is not an admin of the ad account.

Comment: @CBroe, the access token was created int he app (App -> Marketing API -> Tools -> Get Access Token). I've used this instruction (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights-api/getting-started/v2.9) to get the data.

Comment: @PaulBain , do I need admin rights to use this API?

Comment: When I executed a query "**me/adaccounts?fields=campaigns**", in Graph API, I've received a list of client's campaigns. But when I tried to execute a query "**campaign_id_received_from_previous_query/insights?fields=campaign_name**", I've received error #273...